# Why is the pricing of t2.large similar to m4.large?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

They all have 2vcpus and 8G ram.
But with t2.large, you can only use 60% of a single vcpu, average 30% for each of the two vcpus. Even considering the "cpu credits", t2.large seems far weak than m4.large.

Answer (score 11):

The main difference between a `t2` instance and an `m4` instance is the burstable nature of the `t2` instance. (See [T2 instance type documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html).)

While the machines are of similar specification, a `t2.large` instance that is bursting has approximately **60% higher performance** than an `m4.large` instance. However, if the instance runs out of credit then it will be limited in performance.

For an explanation, see the [*T2: From Startups to Enterprise, Performance for a Low Cost*](https://youtu.be/FkMslBsVYFU?t=447) presentation from AWS re:Invent 2016. The difference is explained at the 7m:30s point of the presentation:

[image: T2 performance comparison]

Comment: Could you explain how can t2 get 60% higher than m4? From t2 instance document, the "bursting" is from baseline to 100%, not higher. Just now I launched a t2.medium and a m4.large, made a test using sysbench in ubuntu, they gave almost the same performance.

Comment: A t2.medium is half the price of an m4.large. Could you try the tests again on a t2.large and m4.large (as per the diagram)?

Comment: If not run out of credits t2 instance single thread performance same, I have tested t2.micro & t2.medium. And see the screenshot above, t2.medium faster than c4.large when bursting while t2.medium is also half the price of c4.large, the "pricing logic" not fit here.

Answer (score 3):

I researched this myself and everywhere you look everyone is just talking about bursting.

But it's a fact that the hardware specs for e.g. `t2.large` and `m4.large` are either exactly or roughly the same. That means even if you burst on a `t2` you will get  the same performance as on `m4`.

But AWS, as in the video John Rotenstein linked, claims you still get 60% more performance on `t2`. This is due to a little difference in how AWS defines a `vCPU`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html

> Each vCPU is a thread of a CPU core, except for T2 instances.

So while on `m4` a `vCPU` is a just a **thread**, on `t2` you get a **full core**.

`2 vCPUs` on `m4` is just **1 core with 2 threads** and on `t2` it is **2 full cores but without hyperhtreading**.

You can see this when reading `/proc/cpuinfo`. I used this [script](https://superuser.com/a/583067) to make it easier to read:

t2.large:

> CPU model:  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz 1 CPU,
>   2 physical cores per CPU, total 2 logical CPU units

m4.large:

> CPU model:  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz 1 CPU,
>   1 physical cores per CPU, total 2 logical CPU units

So depending on your application 2 hyperthreading threads on 1 core might result in the same performance as 2 cores, in other use cases the 2 cores perform up to 60% better.

So this little note, noone seems to mention or know about, in their documentation makes the difference.
Hope this clears it up.

Comment: I have made cpu benchmarks and m4.large result was same with t2.large burst.. My understanding of m4.large, you can still run 2 CPUs at 100% usage(total 200%). The 2 threads are not dedicated to a physical CPU(if so, you can only run 100% total), but random of 1|2 from a pool of CPUs. But I'm not very sure..

Comment: yeah, but even if it is a random second cpu you might end up on one where another user is using the other thread at 100%.
so i guess if you are lucky m4 might perform the same.

Comment: I remember there is a thread talking about whether aws over-sell their cpus. If I can not get consistent 100% cpu usage then it is. But whatever it its, the "40%" and "60%" in the video still strange and can not be clearly explained.